# Vector Class - emulating numeric type

Tags: python

I have a python class

```
class Vector2D(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = float(x)
        self.y = float(y)

    def mag(self):
        return sqrt(self.x**2 + self.y**2)

    ...
```

I want to be able to multiply vectors together like `vector1 * vector2`, so I added

```
    def __mul__(self, v):
        return Vector2D(self.x * v.x, self.y * v.y)
```

But I also want to use `new_vector = some_vector * 2` and return  a new vector like so

```
    def __mul__(self, factor):
        return Vector2D(self.x * factor, self.y * factor)
```

How do I do both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to see if `v` is a `Vector2D`, and if not pass it to `float()` and multiply appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

There is no function overload in Python, you have to do it manually.

```
class Vector(object):
  def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
  def __mul__(self, k):
    if type(k) == float or type(k) == int:
      return Vector(self.x * k, self.y * k)
    if type(k) == Vector:
      return Vector(self.x * k.x, self.y * k.y)
    raise "What the hell!?"
  def __str__(self):
    return "<%f, %f>" % (self.x, self.y)


print Vector(1, 2) * Vector(3, 4)
print Vector(1, 2) * 5
```

Comment: is it better to use `type` or `isinstance`?

Comment: @colinmarc: `type()` checks for a specific type. `isinstance()` will catch subclasses.

Comment: Also, comparing the type to `float` or `int` will miss other types that implement number-like behavior.

Comment: (And for the reason you explain, `isinstance` is preferred to `type(...) ==` in almost all the (rare) cases where you do want to typecheck.)

Comment: raising a string has been deprecated for a very, very, very, very, very long time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not incredible with Python, but I'm pretty sure you just write one function and check the type of the second argument.

By the way, why are you multiplying vectors by just multiplying their components? That seems entirely useless.

Comment: it's more of an example. I'm also overriding `__add__`, `__sub__`, `__lt__`, etc and I wanted to know how to operate on it with other vectors as well as regular numbers

Answer (score 0):

Consider that you might want to use numpy for this sort of data.

Comment: I really want to avoid extra dependencies